# Can I get an id of a submitted button in my Controller in Phalcon?

Tags: php, html, forms, phalcon

I'm looking for a way to get the id of a button when the button is submitted. Right now, when I submit the form and dump it in my controller, I can only access the value of the button, nothing else. I was wondering if there's a way to get the id as well. Here's my button in the volt file :

```
{{ submit_button("Forward", "name": "Forward", "class": "btn btn-primary-outline text-white text-sm", 'value':'submit', 'id' : 1) }}
```

I'm trying to check the request in the controller this way:

```
dd($this->request->getPost());
```

And this is the result :

```
Array (2) (
  [Forward] => String (33) "submit"
  [csrf] => String (32) "Y3BiVE9nRFBRWFZ3QTFsQkdoVjFHQT09"
)
```

It only gives me the value, nothing else.
This is my Form :

```
class DashboardForm extends Form
{
    /**
     * @param null $entity
     * @param null $options
     */
    public function initialize($entity = null, $options = null)
    {
        $id = new Hidden('id');
        $this->add($id);
       
        // CSRF
        $csrf = new Hidden('csrf');
        $csrf->addValidator(new Identical([
            'value' => $this->security->getSessionToken(),
            'message' => 'CSRF validation failed'
        ]));
        $csrf->clear();
        $this->add($csrf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `id` use a hidden field to post this data

Comment: `I can only access the value of the button, nothing else`...that's a feature of how HTML forms work. The value of the form element is submitted, using its name as the key. Nothing else. There's nothing PHP/phalcon can do about that. As mentioned above, if you need to submit additional data, consider using another (hidden) field in the form

Comment: sounds better than what i was doing lol thanks!!

Comment: @ADyson This is a good answer, please consider converting it to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can only access the value of the button, nothing else

...that's a feature of how HTML forms work. The value of the form element is submitted, using its name as the key. Nothing else is sent. There's nothing PHP/phalcon can do about that.

As mentioned in another comment, if you need to submit additional data, consider using another (hidden) field in the HTML form to hold that data.